# A definite integral problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to prove:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^x\dfrac{\tfrac{\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+1}{2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}+1}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}\,dx=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: compute the derivative of $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For $x>0$, the integrand is continuous. Take the derivative. And to complete the proof, show that both sides of the equality tends to $0$ when $x\to+0$.